# Iphone Using Accelerometer

Tags: iphone

I have to send a notification to a server in case of iphone free fall in both cases app in foreground

and background. How is it possible

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a continuous running app in the background except in very special cases that are permitted by Apple (which your app is not one of them) as per the below list:

- **Audio**—The app plays audible content to the user while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or video content using AirPlay.)
- **Location**—The app keeps users informed of their location, even while it is running in the background.
- **Voip**—The app provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection.
  newsstand-content—The app is a Newsstand app that downloads and processes magazine or newspaper content in the background.
- **External-accessory**—The app works with a hardware accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the External Accessory framework.
- **Bluetooth-central**—The app works with a Bluetooth accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the Core Bluetooth framework.
- **Bluetooth-peripheral**—The app supports Bluetooth communication in peripheral mode through the Core Bluetooth framework.

You can read the [App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) if you want to implement your app, but it will be probably get rejected if you tried to publish the app to Apple Store